# What am I looking at from inside this downspout drain line?

Tags: plumbing

My downspouts go to a schedule 40 pipe that runs along the house. I am having water problems in the basement that this pipe runs along (they could be totally unrelated, there are other factor at play like poor grading).

I stuck my cheap-o scope as far down this schedule 40 pipe as I can from one of the downspout inlets.

Can you help me understand what I am seeing here? I thought that sections of this pipe should be connected by slightly larger sections of pipe and glued together. Why do the pictures seem to show cement?

[image: disconnected section of pipe?]
[image: weird break?]

Comment: This doesn't look like PVC pipe to me. Maybe cement pipes.

Comment: It's way zoomed-in, but it looks to me sort of like saw-cut ABS joints that have pulled apart.

Comment: It starts out as schedule 40 at the top, but it seems to go into some busted up cement pipes - maybe an old footer drain? Either way, got the scope further in, it's broken in a lot of places. Time to dig.